# Поиск подстроки в последней строке файла

Tags: shell

Я пишу скрипт который из всех файлов по заданной маске должен определить является ли последняя строка файла "Incorrect volume"

```
#!/bin/sh

f=`find -name \*-volume.log`

for file in $f
do
out = `tail -n 1 ${file#*./}`
echo $out
if [$out = "Incorrect volume" ]
then
echo "Privet"
fi
echo ${file#*./}
done
```

Я написал такой код но он не считывает переменную out почему-то а также не принимает условие сравнения строк. Помогите разобраться в ошибке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вообще у вас две синтаксические ошибки:

1. вокруг символа `=` в операторе присвоения не должно быть пробелов:

   ```
   out=...
   ```
2. `[` — это имя программы. да, часто используется внутренняя реализация в интерпретаторе, но синтаксис надо соблюдать. между именем программы и первым аргументом должен быть пробел:

   ```
   [ аргумент ...
   ```

и пара недочётов:

1. строка может содержать пробел, потому в операторе сравнения её надо заключать в кавычки:

   ```
   [ "$out" = "..." ]
   ```
2. если ни одно из имён найденных файлов не может содержать пробела, то всё нормально, а вот если может, вам надо в корне менять весь скрипт (особенно с учётом того, что вы требуете (в шебанге) именно posix-совместимого, т.е., довольно примитивного поведения).

---

а вообще программа для интерпретатора `awk`, проверяющая наличие паттерна в последней строке файла, будет значительно компактнее:

```
$ awk 'END{if(/паттерн/)print FILENAME}' файл
```

если её дополнить вызовом программы `find`, то получим требуемый поиск:

```
$ find -name \*-volume.log -exec awk 'END{if(/паттерн/)print FILENAME}' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

example

```
if [ "$(cat file.txt | grep "Incorrect volume" )"]; then
 echo y
else
 echo n
fi
```

Comment: А если там много таких строк? Мне нужно именно что если эта строка последняя

Comment: @Vlad, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022390/how-to-read-the-second-to-last-line-in-a-file-using-bash

Comment: @Vlad, `s/cat/tail -n 1/`